# Insert structure elements (similar to sections) that only appear in the structure pane and nowhere else?

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks, navigation

i.e. I want to be able to navigate to these elements using the structure pane, but not have them display on my pdf in-text or toc.

Comment: Use the bookmark package.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I am using the bookmark package but I am unaware of any means to omit bookmarks/text in the pdf while having them displayed in the structure tab.

Comment: The bookmark documentation even contains an example. But if you want code: Show a minimal document for tests.